# How do you quickly find the URL for a .NET framework method on MSDN?

Tags: .net, msdn

How to you find the URL that represents the documentation of a .NET framework method on the MSDN website?

For example, I want to embed the URL for the .NET framework method into some comments in some code.  The normal "mangled" URL that one gets searching MSDN isn't very friendly looking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xd12z8ts.aspx.  Using a Google search URL isn't all that pretty looking either.

What I really want a URL that can be embedded in comments that is plain and easy to read.  For example,

// blah blah blah.  See http://<....>/System.Byte.ToString for more information

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough with my question -- I want an URL that is documentation-friendly.  I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple -- just add the name of the method to the end of http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/.

For example, to find the URL for the System.Byte.ToString method go to http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/System.Byte.ToString

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the time you can merely append the lowercase namespace reference to the domain:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application_events.aspx
```

Moreover, for say the .Net 2.0 version (or any specific version) you can add "(VS.80)":

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button(VS.80).aspx
```

Other versions:

- .Net 1.1 -> (VS.71)
- .Net 2.0 -> (VS.80)
- .Net 3.0 -> (VS.85)
- .Net 3.5 -> (VS.90)

Try it for a method (Control.IsInputChar) like so:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputchar.aspx

Comment: Very nice. However, (how) does the schema work when generics are involved? My naive approaches aren't working. I fear there's no solution. :-/

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: there isn't one that I know of, you have to use the mangled name. I'm a bigger fan of Shaun Austin's answer for the more general problem though.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably quickest to just type it into Google in my experience.

EDIT:

Now that you've edited your post to clarify what you actually meant I would say that embedding URLs in your comments is nice but you really have no guarantees that either the mangled URL or the pretty one will exist in future.

Comment: @Shaun Austin: don't forget "site:msdn.microsoft.com" to narrow your search

Answer (score 1):

In my experiecne, googling it works faster than msdn search.

Answer (score 1):

I find that googling "msdn " does it.

ie - msdn System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.ItemDataBound

Answer (score 0):

[Create a Search engine for MSDN Library in Firefox](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/09/learn-to-create-firefox-search-plugin.html)
Like this perhaps?